# how can i know the index of list that user change it

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, class, oop

```
    private List<Profile> _profiles = new List<Profile>();

    public List<Profile> Profiles 
    {
        get
        {
            return _profiles;
        }
        set
        {
            // do here something in the changed index only
        }
    }
```

this is the list of property like a list in parent class , 
is there exist way to know what's the index that the user changed it or not , because i need to do something in changed index only.

can i do the list as property and then in set function let me know where the user update the data

Answer (score 1):

[ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) does support firing events when the list changes; the standard List class doesn't.  You could create your own custom list (implementing IList) if ObservableCollection doesn't suite you (look at the specifics of [CollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) and [PropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653376(v=vs.110).aspx) events to see if it works).

Comment: I think you are trying to say that he should try using INotifyPropertyChange

Comment: Only if you want to track property level changes - sounds like the OP only really needs CollectionChanged, which does raise an event when the list is modified.